# Designing a Database with large number of rows and improving read performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on a Customer Database. I have a table user with userid which identifies a unique users and corresponding to each user there are several other tables like content, playlist, recipe etc. These number of tables are very large.

[image]

Now each of these tables has a boolean attribute "committed". (See fig) This attribute basically decides whether the data is published or not.
When a user adds something new or makes some changes the content is inserted into approproate table with committed = 0.

Once the user clicks on "publish" button, the content with committed=1 now becomes the same as the content with committed = 0.
Now there are more than 100,000 entries for each user for each of these tables and it takes an awful lot of time to find only the unpublished content (calculating difference between committed = 0 and committed = 1). So, most of the data is redundant. The committed attribute is associated with an individual table and not individual attribute. What should be my database design?

Comment: 100,000 rows is definitely **not** considered large. If you have a performance problem, post the table definitions, the indexes for the tables and the actual query you are running. But most importantly: tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using MySQL. Actually fetching the results from the database is not so slow, but I need to do some processing on each of the rows and I need to do it in a loop, so I have to iterate over each row. If I could redesign the database, I could easily reduce the number of records to almost half, since I am storing redundant data mostly.